# Creating Android Facebook-like menu on bottom bar

Tags: android, facebook, menu

I'm using Galaxy tab and it's got a bar on bottom that appears all the time.
FB app shows a new item there that used as a menu button.

How can I declare my menu to be there like FB?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you just want a bar at the bottom?

Comment: post an image and be more  specific about what you want please.

Answer (score 2):

I guess they are still using the old [options menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). You can achieve that effect by setting the target sdk to max 10. I wouldn't recommend that as the menu button hides information and is not the current way to go (I'd use an [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html))

Answer (score 1):

You should definately look at the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). In addition to the tab navigation that is available, you have an option for a split action bar for top and bottom.  ActionBar is part of Honeycomb (3.x), but if you want to support older versions, there is the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library.